# Python - Receiving data from all sockets

Tags: python, sockets, server

I've run into a problem working on a voting system with the Python `socket` module.

Is there a way for a server socket to receive data from client sockets without specifying which one? If not, how would I do so using something else?

Comment: have you actually tried anything?

Answer (score 0):

```
def recv_all():
    messages = {}
    for sock in self.sockets:
        data = sock.recv(4095)
        if data:
           messages[sock] = data
     return messages
```